# Regex for finding URL with different html ending - notepad++

Tags: html, regex, url, notepad++

Can someone help me what expression to use in regex notepad++, I am not a programmer and have tried and read many websites before asking, but still complicated for me.

I need to find the following kind of links having the same beginning but a different ending:

```
http://www.domain.com/buy/best%20iphone%20leather%20case.html  
http://www.domain.com/buy/best%20ipad%20chargers.html  
etc..
```

Thanks

Comment: it wouldnt work because there are many different html endings which needs to be replaced, nit only the main domain.

Comment: You are not being specific. What do you mean by html ending?

Comment: What do you want as result? please give some examples so we can help you.

Comment: i mean the rest of the link after the domain for example best%20iphone%20leather%20case.html maybe its called link ending /Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that.

Find for `domain` and replace it with some other domain name.

Comment: Thanks for your time, maybe i didnt explain properly, i need to find links having the same begining "domain.com/buy/"; but several different endings "best%20iphone%20leather%20case.html" "ending5.html" etc..

Answer (score 0):

1 - Hit `CTRL + h`
2 - Choose the tab `replace`
3 - On the upper field: Type domain you want to replace (olddomain.com)
4 - On the lower field: Type the new domain (newdomain.com)
5 - Hit `enter`.

Comment: Thanks for your time, maybe i didnt explain properly, i need to find links having the same begining "http://www.domain.com/buy/" but several different endings "best%20iphone%20leather%20case.html" "ending5.html" etc..